# Ubuntu 15.10 stucks before login screen on VM Workstation

Tags: boot, login, 15.10, vmware-workstation

I have been working for a couple of months with Ubuntu 15.10 over VM Workstation without any problem.

But now, after a software update from Ubuntu Software Manager, and a reboot, the system cannot boot till login screen. It halts at 'white line' screen before.

[image: White line screen]

I have restarted the VM, but there is no change, it always fails at the same point.

**Is there any option/way to make Ubuntu VM works again**? It is important due to lot of work is inside.

I don't know how access to console/terminal or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the same problem running 15.04 in VMware.

The solution is to restart the VM, get into advanced boot options(for me it means spamming ESC as soon as the VM starts, same principle as getting into [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)). Once there go to Advanced options for Ubuntu, and select an older version(not recovery mode or upstart or whatever, just a plain older kernel version), press enter.

There's instructions on google to make it so that the older version is picked on every boot, if you'd like. Hopefully this issue gets resolved soon.

Comment: I only have one kernel version available to choose so this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

For now you can rollback to the previous version of linux kernel:

```
apt-get --purge remove linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic
```

After applying this command it should pick 4.2.0-27 which works fine. 
Here's "official" bug addressing this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1548587

Comment: This is happening to me and I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is happening to *me* too and I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have kernel choices 4.15.0-{48,50,51}-generic. None of them work. The last thing I did with this VM was install some updates and restart.

Comment: I can get to the login screen by going through advanced boot options, entering a recovery mode, and selecting "resume booting" from within recovery mode, but I cannot get to the login screen from a normal boot.

Comment: @Shayan see this question asked and answered yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149957/unable-to-login-to-account-in-ubuntu-18-04-vmware-workstation-15-after-update